# Can't upload a file from node.js to my route, getting empty request

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file using an upload API, which will upload the file on the remote server. I am using Form Data (form-data) and appending local file. For some unknown reason the uploaded file is always empty. Below is what I am doing.

```
let filename = 'NJ-09_13_22-nodup.csv'
let noDupFile = config.OUTPUT_PATH + '/' + filename
const noDupFileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(noDupFile)
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('chunk', chunk)
       }).on('end', async function () {
           console.log('noDupFileReadStream end')
           const form = new FormData()
           form.append('file', noDupFileReadStream)

           const requestConfig = {
                  headers: {
                     ...form.getHeaders()
                  },
                  httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true, 
                       maxSockets: Infinity })
                }
           axios.post(`${config.XMINDER_URL}/utils/upload`, form, 
                    requestConfig).then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data.url)
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                          console.log(error)
                   })
               })
```

Comment: Remove `data: form` since you're already passing `form` as the 2nd parameter to `axios.post()`. Also, `await` is unnecessary for `createReadStream()`; it doesn't return a promise

Comment: @Phil I see, but unfortunately, it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Everything looks right on the client side. How do you know it's not working? Do you get a particular response or do you also have control over the server side?

Comment: @Phil i am getting socket hung up error. It's a large file which I am trying to upload. Yes I do have access to the server side.

Comment: @Phil I have also updated the code in my question.